# Assign custom roles to the controller Laravel Voyager

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I created a custom page in the Laravel Voyager dashboard but I'm having trouble restricting its access rights.
Using the voyager documentation:

I create key "browse_sendusermails" in permissions table and linked to the admin role

**Route**

```
Route::get('/sendusermails', [App\Http\Controllers\SendUserMailsController::class, 'index'])->middleware('admin.user');
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager;

class SendUserMailsController extends Controller
{
  protected function guard()
  { return Auth::guard(app('VoyagerGuard')); }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->authorize('browse_sendusermails');
        return view('logs.logs');
    }
}
```

But when i click http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sendusermails
It always show 403 This action is unauthorized.

What else can I do to assign custom roles to the controller?

`$this->authorize('sendusermails');` also doesn't work.

Of course when I delete `$this->authorize('browse_sendusermails')` the page loads without a problem

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the gate in `AppServiceProvider` file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AppServiceProvider {
    public function
    boot()
    {
        Gate::define('browse_sendusermails', function ($user) {
           return $user->hasPermission('browse_sendusermails');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for $this->authorize('browse_sendusermails'); works you need a second param as a instance of model like:

```
$this->authorize('browse', new SendUserMails());
```

But if you have a custom Gate like:

```
Gate::define('browse_create_bill', function ($user) {
   return $user->hasPermission(`browse_create_bill`);
});
```

Is not need pass a model as second argument.

Additional if you working in a basic controller (as your case), with this will work:

```
$canView = Auth::user()->can('read', new SendUserMails());
```